# How to user filter with Firestore database in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I want to filter the firestore query to get all docs that do not contain a specific value.

I used `@react-native-firebase`

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
```

```
  const getUnreadDocs = async () => {
    const unreadDocs = await firestore()
      .collection('rooms')
      .doc('aDRKtxbhG9g5IfbKcsa4')
      .collection('messages')
      .where('seen', 'not-in', ['7B6jaZngXeN7V4r3eRoDBdlcj6m2'])
      .get();

    console.log(`unreadDocs`, unreadDocs);
  };
```

docs return from the query

[image: data-from-query]

[query-return-from-docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VFuS.png)

How data is stored?

we have collection

```
rooms Collection -> Docs -> fields
         |
         V
     messages Collection -> Docs -> fields
```

[rooms-collection-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w36c5.png)

[image: messages-collection-img1]

[messages-collection-img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcd05.png)

What should the query return?
as we mention in query, docs should not contain `7B6jaZngXeN7V4r3eRoDBdlcj6m2` in the `seen` field

so, query should return only one doc i.e.

[messages-collection-img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9gR.png)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded `value`? If so, can you show us that code instead, as well as a screenshot of a document that is returns by the query that you think should not be returned?

Comment: Yes, I reproduce the problem with a hard-coded `value`, I updated the docs in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in`/`not-in` operators checks if a current single-value field has a value that exists/does not exist in a list of values you specify. But your `seen` field is an array, which won't work with this operator.

Instead you'll want to use `array-contains` on that to check if a value **is** present. There is no equivalent `array-does-not-contain` operator to check whether a value is not present in the array field.

Also see:

- [Firestore - Possible to query by array-not-contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595938/firestore-possible-to-query-by-array-not-contains)
- [Firestore get documents where value not in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085868/firestore-get-documents-where-value-not-in-array)