# Flutter Firestore ArrayNotContains?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the following code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('alerts').where('acknowledge', arrayContains: user?.uid).snapshots();
```

but I need arrayContains to be arrayNotContains? Is there a simple way to do this? I have done a search and it seems others have struggled with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "array-not-contains" operator in Cloud Firestore at the moment.

I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52088676/6514762), as it explains why this operation is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for that. I think modifying the array to be a string : bool array might be the answer. Really appreciate the link.