# About Firestore query

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

i have a `const existInterestClassId:any[] = [];` and inside will contain some id.

And i have to do another query in firestore.

```
const ineterestClassDocs = await ineterestClassCollection.where('status', '==', 'A').get();
```

i want to add one more statement that is if the id not equal to the array value.  is there any possible way to do it ? for example like

```
const ineterestClassDocs = await ineterestClassCollection 
.where('status', '==', 'A') 
.where('id', '!=' 'existInterestClassID all value') 
.get();
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `not-in` operator?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article.

[Firebase firestore retrieve documents that are not in a document array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085868/firestore-get-documents-where-value-not-in-array)

You can use the `array-contains` operator in Firestore to check if an array field contains a certain value. To achieve your desired result, you can use the `not-in` operator to exclude documents that have an id field that matches any value in the existInterestClassId array.

And there is an opposite article, unfortunately I am little busy now, so I can't check which is the best option for you.

[Firestore get documents where value not in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085868/firestore-get-documents-where-value-not-in-array)

Comment: But my id is not a array field. Is this still can work ?

Comment: Isn't it an array? `const existInterestClassId:any[] = [];`